# Inserting Data to a particular section in crystal report VS2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am developing marks card for my college which consists of Student name, Student rollnum, subject name with their subject code and marks of their respective subject scored by student. I have a database which has a definition as shown below :

```
Name    |Roll Num   |SubjectCode    |SubjectName    |Marks
Std_Name 1001        Phy              Physics        65
Std_Name 1001        Che              Chemistry      59
Std_Name 1001        Math             Mathematics    69
```

From the above table, I want to get SubjectCode, SubjectName and Marks to datatable/dataset/datagrid and insert those 
data to particular section(section 1,Section 2,..etc) in Crystal Report. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn more about

**[how to create a crystal report with dataset?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28899/Crystal-Report-with-DataSet-and-DataTable-using-C)**

Inserting fields in section is not a big issue. You just need to create dataset or datatable and reference it to your crystal report. After designing report you can pass the dataset object to the crystal report with data.

You should also learn about each section and their role.

**Report Header:** This section is printed at the top of the first page of report. You can put here company name, address etc. which should not come on next page.

**Page Header:** This section is printed at the top of the each page of report. you can put page number, column header labels (Subject Code, Subject Name, Marks, etc).

**Detail Section:** This section will print the records in a row form. So, you can put here your fields so, the values will be displayed as you want.

**Page Footer and Report Footer:** These sections are self descriptive after understanding the above two. In Report Footer section you can put comments which should be printed at the bottom of the last page and In Page Footer section you can put Sum of values like total marks, total out of marks, etc. You can also put these fields in Report footer section if there are multiple pages are printed and you wanted print the total only on last page.

There are also another section type is Group Header and Group Footer. When you want to display record group wise and the header and footer should be printed also group wise then you can use this section here.

Comment: Shell, thank you for the detailed description about Crystal Report. As I am a newbie, I think I didn't explained my problem in detail. My exact problem is I want to display SubjectCode,SubjectName and Marks in particular section of my report. As SubjectCode,SubjectName and Marks keeps changing for each student, I want a particular section to print those data in a particular section. How can I do this? I have successfully implemented dataset to my report where I am fetching individual data such as name and rollnum, but I am stuck with the inserting set of data to particular section.

Comment: If you are populating data for multiple students. So, in this case you can use grouping. You don't need to put the detail for particular student in seperate section. Grouping will help you to make it seperate.You can add group by Group expert option. in this window you need to select student id or code. how crystal report will create another two sections group header and group footer as i have mentioned in my answer. where you can place the header and footer detail. **[Read Group in Crystal Report](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142064/Step-by-Step-Creation-of-Crystal-Report-using-its)**